# Simple RNN Model not working due to issue with tfVariable in TF2

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a simple model and save the untrained layers. (I'll later want to train it).  I'm trying to use tensorflow core API's without relying on Keras layers so I can more directly control what I use and maximize compatibility with TFLite.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class BasicModel(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.const = None

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,20],dtype=tf.int32),
    ])
    def rnn(self, captions):
        # ENCODER
        weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10000, 724]))#, shape=[vocab_size,embedding_dimension], name="embedding_weights")
        embedding_output = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(weights,captions)
        #activation is tanh for GRUCell
        sequence = tf.unstack(embedding_output,num=20, axis=1) 
        cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(20)
        print(sequence)
        gru_layer = tf.compat.v1.nn.static_rnn(cell, sequence, dtype=tf.float32)
        return gru_layer

root = BasicModel()
concrete_function = root.rnn.get_concrete_function()
tf.saved_model.save(root,"model",concrete_function)
```

I expect to have an untrained model that saves but instead I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_tensorflow_2.py", line 24, in <module>
    concrete_function = root.rnn.get_concrete_function()#tf.constant(images), tf.constant(captions), tf.constant(cap_lens))
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 782, in get_concrete_function
    return self._stateless_fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1891, in get_concrete_function
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2150, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2041, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 358, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2658, in bound_method_wrapper
    return wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 905, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in converted code:

    model_tensorflow_2.py:13 rnn  *
        weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10000, 724]))#, shape=[vocab_size,embedding_dimension], name="embedding_weights")
    /Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:260 __call__
        return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:254 _variable_v2_call
        shape=shape)
    /Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:65 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /Users/t.capes/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py:413 invalid_creator_scope
        "tf.function-decorated function tried to create "

    ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

Comment: You might want to consider using Sonnet 2. `snt.Module` is just a thin abstraction on top of `tf.Module` which adds automatic name scoping and variable tracking. Sonnet 2 also comes with a few builtin modules, including RNNs. See https://sonnet.readthedocs.io for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.function` does not allow to create variables on non-first call, because the semantics of that are not clear: should the variables be re-created on each call? should they be implicitly cached? (see [this bit](https://youtu.be/Up9CvRLIIIw) in the "tf.function and AutoGraph" talk from TF Summit 2019).

A common workaround is to have a helper function creating the variables and ensure that it's called at most once for each instance:

```
class BasicModel(tf.Module):
    # ...

    def _create_parameters(self, ...):
        self._weights = tf.Variable(...)
        self._parameters_created = True

    def rnn(self, ...):
        if not self._parameters_created:
            self._create_parameters(...)
        ...
```